# SoftwareBitmap uses lot of memory

Tags: c#, image, memory-management, bitmap, uwp

I am loading some JPEG and PNG images into [GridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.gridview). I am using [Software Bitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.graphics.imaging.softwarebitmap) to represent the images.

However, `SoftwareBitmap` stores an *uncompressed* form of the image. So the problem is, when loading multiple (many) images, my app eats lots of RAM, and I am concerned about high memory usage.

I have known that the `GridView` handles virtualization by itself.

While loading only about 150 images (90 MB as compressed image files on disk), the app's memory usage rises close to 500 MB!

How can I optimize? Do I need to use some `SoftwareBitmap` feature or it's alternative I am unaware of? Or will I have to do some kind of image processing to store compressed version in the RAM (I don't even know if that's possible).

Comment: Applications like Explorer and other image viewers use thumbnails to display images in fast way.

Comment: Why are you not just using standard XAML image? `<Image Source="{Binding ImagePath}" />` will give you much better performance for many reasons - it uses a system-maintained image cache and only decodes the image at render size (and off-thread too). As soon as you declare an explicit image source (even BitmapImage) you're throwing away platform optimizations.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake That's because I need the pixel data to calculate hashes of these images using a custom algorithm.

Comment: @VijayChavda you'll still not want to use SoftwareBitmap - CanvasBitmap will be lighter on memory and perform better (as it's hardware backed - unlike SoftwareBitmap for obvious reasons). Ideally you'll also want to decode to render size.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Also the images are dynamically loaded from user specified folder from disk, not my image assets. So I have to use BItmapImage or something.

Comment: @JohnnyWestlake Okay, I think I might have some idea here. I'll get back to you after some changes :)